# Продукти тривалого чи довготривалого зберігання?

Tags: вибір-слова

Як буде правильно чи обидва варіанти? На мою думку, тривале зберігання — це і є довготривале.

Comment: Вітаємо на Ukrainian Language StackExchange! Чи є у вас аргументи за чи проти використання кожного слова? Будь ласка, почитайте про [наші критерії](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/), за якими ми оцінюємо хороші питання. Ви завжди можете виправити питання - для цього натисніть [edit].

Comment: @Artemix, а, по-моєму, прийнятне і цікаве запитання. Звісно, було б краще, якби автор провів якесь початкове дослідження сам. Але, можливо, він навіть не знає інструментів для цього. Як на мене, [це](//ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/4) — це більше те, що ми маємо вимагати від нас самих, особливо під час приватної бети, а не від інших; так, і від інших теж — але в ідеалі, а не відразу від самого початку, і особливо не від запитань. (P.S.: А «плюс» не я поставив.)

Comment: Прикол у тому, що «[Словник української мови](http://sum.in.ua)» вважає «тривалий», «довготривалий» і «довгочасний» синонімами. Але при цьому мені абсолютно не зрозуміло — яке з цих слів може інтерпретуватися в повсякденному житті як «те, що призначане для довгого зберігання», а яке як «те, що вже довго провалялося на полиці». Чи вони в цьому значенні абсолютно еквіватентні?

Comment: Можу лише висловити припущення що у якійсь термінологічній послідовності "продукт тривалого збереження" може бути декілька тижнів, а "довготривалого" - декілька місяців. Як наприклад є "пастерізований" і "суперпастерізований".

Answer (score 7):

Згідно зі «Словником української мови» в 11 томах:

- > **[ДОВГОТРИВА́ЛИЙ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=23065&page=783)**. Який довго триває, існує і т. ін.; довгочасний.
- > **[ДОВГОЧА́СНИЙ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=23068&page=783)**. Те саме, що довготрива́лий. // 
  >   Здатний довго існувати, розрахований на довгий період.
- > **[ДО́ВГИЙ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=23025&page=781)**. **2.** Який займає великий відрізок часу; тривалий, довгочасний. // Протяжний, довготривалий.
- > **[ТРИВА́ЛИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/tryvalyj)**. **1.** Який довго тривав або триває, продовжується й т. ін.; довгочасний.

---

Наразі точно я можу сказати лише одне: «продукт тривалого зберігання» теоретично можна інтерпретувати не лише як «продукт, пристосований до тривалого зберігання», а й як «продукт, що довго зберігався (лежав на полиці)». Це формально випливає з означення «який довго *тривав* або триває…» (тобто, можливо, зберігання *тривало* довго, а не буде тривати). Тим не менше, наскільки така незручна інтерпретація ймовірна, чи варто через це використовувати інші слова і чи позбавлені інші слова можливості такої інтерпретації — я, на жаль, сказати не можу. Тобто, фактично, відповідь наразі лише часткова — я не можу повноцінно відповісти на Ваше запитання. Можливо, в контексті «*таке-то* зберігання» ці прикметники повністю синонімічні, а, можливо, й ні.

Upd.: У [«Німецько-руському словарі»](//books.google.com/books?id=_UtRAAAAcAAJ&q=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9) (1867, Львів, друкарня М. Ф. Поремби) і «довготривалий», і «тривалий» надаються як переклади до німецького «[langwierig](//de.wiktionary.org/wiki/langwierig)» (також «тривалий» надається як переклад для «[beständig](//de.wiktionary.org/wiki/best%C3%A4ndig)», «[dauerhaft](//de.wiktionary.org/wiki/dauerhaft)», «[haltbar](//de.wiktionary.org/wiki/haltbar)» — але це відповідає вже другому значенню цього слова за СУМ-11 — «тривкий», «витривалий» — що є поза темою питання). Ймовірно, «довготривалий» і «тривалий» уже в 1867 році були синонімами (якщо не брати до уваги додаткових значень «тривалий», які поза темою) — і, на мою думку, немає сенсу вважати їх не такими зараз. Проте, як тоді, так і зараз слово «тривалий» використовується значно частіше; здається, що «довготривалий» є просто посиленням слова «тривалий», що вживається суб'єктивно на розсуд автора.

---

Також існує ряд прикметників, що теоретично можна застосовувати не лише до іменника «зберігання», а й до самих продуктів. Це вже назване вище «довгочасний» і «[довговічний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=23032&page=782)». Наприклад, «довгочасне житло», «довговічний матеріал». Тим не менше застосування цих прикметників до деяких видів продуктів видається мені стилістично небажаним. Окрім того, це може мати інший відтінок значення, наприклад, те, чого за кількістю / за планом певному колективу має вистачити надовго, а не те, що за своєю природою може не псуватися довго.

Answer (score 6):

У наказах і інструкціях МОЗ йдеться саме про *тривале* зберігання.

- [Про затвердження Інструкції з організації харчування дітей у дошкільних навчальних закладах](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/z0523-06)

> Ураховуючи   можливі  перебої  у  постачанні  продуктів  харчування, 
>   у  дошкільному  навчальному  закладі   повинен   бути  двотижневий 
>   запас рибних,  м'ясних консервів,  молочних продуктів  *тривалого*
>   терміну зберігання,  фруктів.

- [Про затвердження Санітарних правил і норм по застосуванню харчових добавок](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/z0715-96)

> Введення антиоксидантів  у  жири  допускається   тільки   при 
>   виробництві  харчових жирів,  призначених для *тривалого* зберігання 
>   (більш 3-х місяців).  Антиоксиданти слід  вводити  у  високоякісні 
>   свіжі жири.

- [ІНСТРУКЦІЯ з діловодства у Міністерстві охорони здоров’я України](http://moz.gov.ua/docfiles/dod143_1__2014.pdf)

> Описи справ постійного (*тривалого*) зберігання

Answer (score 4):

Як вказав Sasha [тривалий](http://sum.in.ua/s/tryvalyj), [довготривалий](http://sum.in.ua/s/dovghotryvalyj) та [довгочасний](http://sum.in.ua/s/dovghochasnyj) — синоніми. Але дуже рідко коли синоніми мають абсолютно однакове значення. Якщо є декілька слів із схожим значенням у мові вони поступово беруть на себе якісь окремі смисли.

У коментарі до питання я висловив припущення що **тривалий** та **довготривалий** як терміни можуть розрізняти різницю у тривалості зберігання продуктів і як приклад навів "пастерізований" та "суперпастерізований". Цікаво що Гугл знайшов таку цитату:

> молоко суперпастеризоване, [довготривалого](http://z.texty.org.ua/deal/45474) зберігання жирністю 2,5%

Більшість знайдених сторінок "довготривалого зберігання" — описують заходи для зберігання продуктів, їх пакування, обладнання (морозильні камери), тощо. Тобто "довготривалий" часто описує способи **максимально** тривалого зберігання продуктів (коли просто тривалого вже недостатньо). Але трапляються і сторінки де продуктами довготривалого зберігання називають і крупи,

Каталог товарів HausKit:

> [Термосумка](http://hauskit.com.ua/ua/products/214) використовується для довготривалого зберігання охолоджених продуктів.

Сирохман І.В. Товарознавство пакувальних матеріалів і тари:

> Заморожене м'ясо втрачає **протягом року** 1,5—2,5 % маси. Якщо його упаковувати у вологонепроникну плівку (наприклад поліетилен), ці втрати можна скоротити до 0,1% і нижче. Для [довготривалого](http://tovar.dt-kt.net/books/book-14/chapter-1372/) зберігання замороженого м'яса використовують тришарові співекструзійні плівки на основі поліетилену.

Greenteam - Технологія зберігання:

> Поступове зниження температури в камері ... забезпечує довгострокове зберігання цибулі **до 8 місяців**. Для зберігання моркви, буряку, капусти ДУЖЕ ВАЖЛИВО! використовувати сировину, яка вирощувалася саме для [довготривалого](https://www.greenteam.ua/index.php/kontrol-kachestva/tekhnologiya-zberigannya) зберігання.

Сирохман І. В. Товарознавство харчових продуктів функціонального призначення:

> Термізовані молочні продукти [довготривалого](http://p-for.com/book_470_glava_84_10.2._KLASIF%D0%86KA%D0%A1%D0%86JA_%D0%86_FORM.html) зберігання, наприклад, десерт на основі сиру кисломолочного або термізований сметанний продукт. Термін придатності термізованого продукту з пектином, залежно від обладнання, способу фасування й упаковки — перевищує **30 діб**.

Ну і на додачу, є такий фактор як "канцелярит" або офіційно-бюрократичний стиль який тяжіє до довгих, складних слів. Це явище також може призводити до вибору з двох синонімів "тривалий" і "довготривалий" саме останнього через його складність.

Comment: Мені здається, що роль також відіграють сполучники (чи їхня відсутність). Не кожний прикметник чи зворот легко вживається у конструкції «продукт *такого-то* зберігання» без прийменника (при тому, що словосполучення «*таке-то* зберігання» існує). Наприклад, легко сказати «молоко тривалого зберігання», а от «молоко зберігання в холодильнику» — ні (при тому, що в довшу конструкцію «продукт, *призначений для* такого-то зберігання» ми можемо запхнути і «тривале зберігання» і «зберігання в холодильнику»).

Comment: Пошук у лейпцизькому корпусі показує, що зліва від «[тривалого](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=тривалого)» слово «для» стоїть майже **в два рази рідше**, ніж слово «товар*», в той час як зліва від «[довготривалого](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=довготривалого)» слово «для» стоїть майже **в 3,5 рази частіше**, ніж слово «товар*». Отака штука.

Comment: Складається враження, що «***щось* тривалого зберігання**» — це вже якийсь сталий вислів, в той час як «*щось* довготривалого зберігання» хоча й іноді кажуть, але не частіше, ніж використовують оте «довготривале зберігання» у загальних контекстах типу «для довготривалого зберігання використовуйте термосумку».